# How can I disable Firefox for Android default URL suggestions?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I wiped, formatted, and then installed the latest Lineage OS for my device.

When I install Firefox, before I ever browse anything and after turning search suggestions off, I see URL suggestions whenever I begin to type an address.

For example, if I type 't', the URL bar suggests twitter.com; 'ta' target.com; 'te' telegraph.co.uk; 'ti' ticketmaster.com; 'to' toysrus.com; 'tu' tumblr.com; 'aa' aa.com; 'ac' accuweather.com; etc.

I cannot find where to tun off these suggestions, and there is no reasonable way to avoid these suggestions, and 100% are completely useless for me. I want my URL bar to only offer me the suggestions of sites that I have actually visited, not all this garbage noise that Mozilla is puking into my face with.

Comment: We can't answer "why", though it seems obvious that _other people_ might find them useful.  Generally they're done via a lookup service, not built in.

Comment: @MatthewRead Can you please kindly review my edited title and inform me as to whether it meets your approval? Can you graciously extend the time to inform me what a "lookup service, not built in" is?

Comment: Paul: the websites it suggests, have they been visited by you in the past using that browser?

Comment: @Firelord No, I visited zero sites before receiving those suggestions.

Comment: [this site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/autocomplete-settings-firefox-focus-address-bar) seems to at least acknowledge the fuctionality in a mozilla product.  It didn't help me, unfortunately, but it seems like a step toward finding a solution.

Comment: This is a small inconvenience you have to bear to continue enjoying an free and open-source web browser. These companies pay Mozilla to keep them in default suggestions.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig The result of this is it discourages me from donating money, so they are forever on the teet of the oligarchs.

Comment: It seems to be paradox. Only with enough donor's money would they be able to get off the oligarchs' teets.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible without disabling autocomplete completely and Mozilla maintainers refuse to change it, see this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267208

Comment: I'm convinced someone is paying them to put it there. It is the same effect as an advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the firefox configuration manually; it worked on my phone.

1.Type about:config in the address bar.

2. Set "browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled" to "False".
3. Type "ta" in the address bar. It should no longer autocomplete to "target.com"

Comment: This eliminates the autocomplete function. I just want to make the ads go away.

Comment: But that is exactly what you wanted i.e. for Firefox to stop suggesting URLs. No mention of ads in your question.

Comment: I stated that I cannot find where to turn off these suggestions, indicating that I don't want to turn off all suggestions.

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to turn off only the `default' suggestions.